# Set the URL in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf

I am using the code below to convert a web page to PDF using HtmlToPdf

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.AddPage(converter.ConvertUrl(url).Pages[0]);

            // save pdf document 
doc.Save("D:\\test.pdf");

            // close pdf document 
doc.Close();
```

Here I need to pass the URL, my URL is a MVC view, I have used below code

```
UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
            string url = u.Action("_GenerationPdf", "Generation", null);


public ActionResult _GenerationPdf()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But when executing it return error Navigation timeout.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Make sure that your website is actually running & that the URL is correct when you try to open & convert it. Print or capture the generated URL, and open it in a browser to verify.

Comment: actually the url is ""/Generation/_GenerationPdf" when running.

Comment: You probably need to add the protocol + servername: `http://myserver` before the url.