# Navigation Timeout when converting URL to PDF using SelectPdf HtmlToPDF in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf

I've got an issue with a website I'm working with. There's a function where you download a PDF from a page within our application. The download works fine when in certain environments like my local and the production environment, but in our testing environment it fails.

After adding some logging, I found that it was timing out on the ConvertUrl(url) function:

```
System.Exception: Conversion error: Navigation timeout.
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.?(String A_0, ?[]& A_1, ?& A_2)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.?(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(String url)
```

What I did after was get it to log what the url was and navigate to it in my browser. And it loaded fine with the information I needed in the PDF.

The code, somewhat cut down to hide unnecessary and privileged information is this:

```
string url = String.Format("{0}/Controller/DownloadPDF/{1}?d={2}}", EnvironmentConfig.RootURL, model.DocID);

HtmlToPdf converter = ConfigurePDFConverter(model);

// set authentication cookie
converter.Options.HttpCookies.Add(
    ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie",
    context.Request.Cookies[".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"].Value);

doc = converter.ConvertUrl(url); // fails here

reportPDF = doc.Save();
```

The URL itself seems fine and there isn't anything wrong with it when running it in the browser, so I'm not sure what else I can look at. I've tried setting converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime to 10 minutes, but it just kept running for the 10 minutes and failing afterwards.

What should I look for here? Common issues or settings that may cause this problem? It's strange because this is the only environment that this issue happens in.

I had a look at [Set the URL in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931878/set-the-url-in-mvc) which looked like a similar issue, but no solution was provided and the comments on it did not help my situation.